# Need help Sorting Through Data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to clean some data for a computational biology research project. However, an issue is coming up where some dogs born from the same litter on the same day have the same mother but multiple fathers. I need to find these data points and return them in some for so that I can manually go back to the documents and check them. Does anyone know a better way so that each set doesn't take 30+ minutes to finish?

I have been trying to use pandas to go through the data so far, and I'm no CS wizard. I basically used a for loop to check the data each individually and even the smaller sets have around 10k pieces of data.

```py
data = raw_data.loc[:,['Order', 'Name', 'Sire', 'Dam', 'Registration', 'DOB']]
length = len(data.index)

for i in range(0,length,1):
    for j in range(i+1,length,1):
        if (data.iat[i,5]==data.iat[j,5]): #Same date of birth
            if (data.iat[i,3]==data.iat[j,3]): #Same mother
                if (data.iat[i,2]!= data.iat[j,2]): #Different father
                    print(data.iat[i,0]+data.iat[j,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group your data by date of birth and mother, then calculate the number of different values for the father columns. The result will be calculated for every group of DOB and Dam. You will be interested in all the groups with a result greater than 1.

```
import pandas as pd
data.groupby(by=['DOB','Dam']).\ # Group your data by 'DOB' and 'Dam'
aggregate({'Sire':pd.Series.nunique}).\ # Count distinct values for 'Sire' in each group
sort_values(by="Sire", ascending= False).\ # Descending order of the results
query("Sire > 1").\ # Take the 'DOB' and 'Dam' pairs with more than 1 'Sire'
to_excel("File_with_results.xlsx") # Write the results to an excel file
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, and I've been trying to understand most of the functions you used so far. I'm curious why you need to do the `sort_values(by="Sire", ascending = False) `, is this just an extra step to make the data cleaner?  

Also, I'm having an issue where you used `query` where the code tells me that Sire is a string and cannot be compared to an integer.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enought with funtcion explanation.
As you said, `sort_values(by="Sire", ascending = False)` is just for make the data cleaner.
For the 'Sire' issue, a data type transform might do the job, but can you post a data sample, please?

Comment: Hi, sorry for taking a while to reply - had to get permission for data sharing.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13EMLPE538sHc4jAThQXuzONHAmewGHeA/view?usp=sharing

This link should let you get a sample data set that I am working with

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

One additional suggestion beyond Miguel's.

For testing I would trim down your file to a small sample that includes the issue you are working on. You don't want to waste CPU time until you know the program is behaving.

BDS